# how to batch a variable length spectogram in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have to train a denoising autoencoder but i need to batch the 5-frame noisy powerspectrum with 1 frame clean powerspectrum , but i dono how to batch the spectrogram since my data are all variable length in time-series.

```
def parse_line(noise_file,clean_file):
    noise_binary = tf.read_file(noise_file)
    noise_binary = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(noise_binary, file_format='wav', samples_per_second=16000, channel_count=1)
    noise_stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(tf.reshape(noise_binary, [1, -1]), frame_length=512, frame_step=256,fft_length=512)
    noise_powerspectrum = tf.log(tf.abs(noise_stfts)**2)
    noise_data = tf.squeeze(tf.contrib.signal.frame(noise_powerspectrum,frame_length=5,frame_step=1,axis=1))
    clean_binary = tf.read_file(clean_file)
    clean_binary = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(clean_binary, file_format='wav', samples_per_second=16000, channel_count=1)
    clean_stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(tf.reshape(clean_binary, [1, -1]), frame_length=512, frame_step=256,fft_length=512)
    clean_powerspectrum = tf.log(tf.abs(clean_stfts)**2)
    clean_data = tf.squeeze(clean_powerspectrum)[:-4]
    return noise_data, clean_data
```

my tf.data pipeline is as shown below

```
shuffle_batch = 10
batch_size = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((noise_datalist,clean_datalist))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_batch) # shuffle number of files perbatch
dataset = dataset.map(parse_line,num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = dataset.get_next()
```

this is the errors that shows

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [443,5,257] and element 1 had shape [280,5,257].
 [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

when i change the batch_size to 1 it works and get one data. How can I batch this variable length data or even maybe batch all data to 1 like [443,5,257] and [280,5,257] to [723,5,257]?

Comment: 443 and 280 corresponds to shapes of your noisy data and clean data respectively?

Comment: @kvish my noisy data are created from clean_data, so they are same size, but i have many different time in length of wav files(clean_data) and i read it from noise_datalist and clean_datalist . i have a list of noise and clean data like data1.wav, data2.wav which is different length of time which shows in the post, for example data1.wav have 443frames, data2.wav and 280 frames and etc.

Comment: oh okay thanks for clearing that up. Would [padding and batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) change the context of what you are trying to do? It might produce different lengths of first component in different batches according to what is the maximum in that batch, if you do not know what is the overall max length that you would want to use.